# Google Maps API v3 - disabled on domain (Hello World example)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to do something with the google maps api, but it always says that is has been disabled, although i just tried the Hello World example from the website here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=de#HelloWorld

Somebody an idea ?

Comment: Are you using an API key?  If so, do you own that key?  If so, make sure that the key allows the domain you're hosting your site on.

Comment: Yes, I do. And yes, I do. My domains are listed in the Google API Console.

Comment: It looks like the authentication is broken, for the last several hours.  For now, test with no API key.

Comment: Works without key, really seems to be a google error. Thanks !

Comment: We experienced a technical issue during a regular update to the Google Maps API Console. The outage began affecting sites this afternoon, and impacted all sites using an API console key with both JavaScript Maps API versions 2 and 3. Services were fully restored by 5:30pm PT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a google error on their end...

http://www.google.com.au/about/jobs/locations/sydney/